# Javascript how to merge two child arrays as a single array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to make an array flat.

```js
// example of the start array
const myArray = [
  [ 
    { foo: "bar", baz: "qux"},
    { quux: "corge", grault: "garply" }
  ],
  [
    { waldo: "fred", plugh: "xyzzy" },
    { thud: "barbra", streisand: "woohoo" }
  ]
];
```

However I'd like it to be:

```js
// end result
[
  { foo: "bar", baz: "qux"},
  { quux: "corge", grault: "garply" },
  { waldo: "fred", plugh: "xyzzy" },
  { thud: "barbra", streisand: "woohoo" }
]
```

Now the following example gives the result: `(2) [Array(2), Array(2)]`.

```js
const myArray = [
  [ 
   { foo: "bar", baz: "qux"},
    { quux: "corge", grault: "garply" }
  ],
  [
   { waldo: "fred", plugh: "xyzzy" },
    { thud: "barbra", streisand: "woohoo" }
  ]
];

let newArray = [];
myArray.forEach((subArray) => newArray.push(subArray));
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: You can use `myArray.flat()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can flatten the arrays using [`Array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat):

```js
const myArray = [
  [ 
    { foo: "bar", baz: "qux"},
    { quux: "corge", grault: "garply" }
  ],
  [
    { waldo: "fred", plugh: "xyzzy" },
    { thud: "barbra", streisand: "woohoo" }
  ]
];

const newArray = myArray.flat();

console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [*spread* operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to get what you want (but this is a quick fix, there are better ways to do it):

```js
const myArray = [
  [ 
   { foo: "bar", baz: "qux"},
    { quux: "corge", grault: "garply" }
  ],
  [
   { waldo: "fred", plugh: "xyzzy" },
    { thud: "barbra", streisand: "woohoo" }
  ]
];

let newArray = [];
myArray.forEach((subArray) => newArray.push(subArray));
newArray = [...newArray[0], ...newArray[1]];
console.log(newArray);
```

Comment: Spread operator is not compatible with all browsers, so you should add this information to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use concat to merge arrays:

```js
const myArray = [
  [ 
    { foo: "bar", baz: "qux"},
    { quux: "corge", grault: "garply" }
  ],
  [
    { waldo: "fred", plugh: "xyzzy" },
    { thud: "barbra", streisand: "woohoo" }
  ]
];

const merged = [].concat.apply([], myArray);
console.log(merged);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat):

```
const myArray = [
  [ 
    { foo: "bar", baz: "qux"},
    { quux: "corge", grault: "garply" }
  ],
  [
    { waldo: "fred", plugh: "xyzzy" },
    { thud: "barbra", streisand: "woohoo" }
  ]
];

let newArray = [];
myArray.forEach(
    (subArray) => {
        newArray = newArray.concat(subArray);
    }
);
console.log(newArray);
```